# how resolve java.io.InvalidClassException: local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class serializable in a so big project coded without specify serialVersionUID, and save in a dataBase MySQL as a blob!

I have to add some fields to this class, but after doing this, I get an exception like this:

```
IOException: error when reading object
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException:
IOException: error when reading object at
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datatype.BlobImpl.getObject(BlobImpl.java:134)

.
. 
..

Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException:
local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1113799434508676095,
local class serialVersionUID = -8504143738844344601 at
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:560)
```

This is all the stackTrace:

```
IOException: error when reading object
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: IOException: error when reading object
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datatype.BlobImpl.getObject(BlobImpl.java:134)
at      org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.AbstractLargeBinaryRDBMSMapping.getObject(AbstractLargeB    inaryRDBMSMapping.java:271)
at     org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.SingleFieldMapping.getObject(SingleFieldMapping.java:21    9)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.fieldmanager.ResultSetGetter.fetchObjectField(ResultSetGetter.java:153)
at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:1197)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.ra.impl.RAOrganizationRecordImpl.jdoReplaceField(RAOrganizationRecordImpl.java)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.ra.impl.BaseRARecordImpl.jdoReplaceFields(BaseRARecordImpl.java)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.replaceFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2772)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.PersistentIDROF$1.fetchFields(PersistentIDROF.java:441)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.loadFieldValues(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:841)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.initialiseForHollowAppId(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:284)
at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerFactory.newStateManagerForHollowPopulatedAppId(StateManagerFactory.java:116)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObjectUsingAID(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2117)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.PersistentIDROF.getObjectForApplicationId(PersistentIDROF.java:435)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.PersistentIDROF.getObject(PersistentIDROF.java:301)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.nextResultSetElement(ForwardQueryResult.java:130)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult$QueryResultIterator.next(ForwardQueryResult.java:282)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.detachCopyAll(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1176)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerProxy.detachCopyAll(JDOPersistenceManagerProxy.java:166)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.ra.impl.RAOrganizationStore.getRecords(RAOrganizationStore.java:136)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.ra.impl.RAOrganizationManagerImpl.getRecords(RAOrganizationManagerImpl.java:174)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.admin.actions.OrganizationAction.browse(OrganizationAction.java:246)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.admin.interceptors.UrlInterceptor.intercept(UrlInterceptor.java:47)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.admin.interceptors.MonitoringInterceptor.intercept(MonitoringInterceptor.java:47)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.admin.interceptors.TransactionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionInterceptor.java:36)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.admin.interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.ra.RAOrganization; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1666617984322225572, local class serialVersionUID = 6311293439415161861
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:560)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1599)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1494)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1748)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datatype.BlobImpl.getObject(BlobImpl.java:122)
... 102 more
Nested Throwables StackTrace:
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.ra.RAOrganization; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1666617984322225572, local class serialVersionUID = 6311293439415161861
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:560)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1599)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1494)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1748)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datatype.BlobImpl.getObject(BlobImpl.java:122)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.AbstractLargeBinaryRDBMSMapping.getObject(AbstractLargeBinaryRDBMSMapping.java:271)
at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.SingleFieldMapping.getObject(SingleFieldMapping.java:219)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.fieldmanager.ResultSetGetter.fetchObjectField(ResultSetGetter.java:153)
at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:1197)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.ra.impl.RAOrganizationRecordImpl.jdoReplaceField(RAOrganizationRecordImpl.java)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.ra.impl.BaseRARecordImpl.jdoReplaceFields(BaseRARecordImpl.java)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.replaceFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2772)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.PersistentIDROF$1.fetchFields(PersistentIDROF.java:441)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.loadFieldValues(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:841)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.initialiseForHollowAppId(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:284)
at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerFactory.newStateManagerForHollowPopulatedAppId(StateManagerFactory.java:116)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObjectUsingAID(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2117)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.PersistentIDROF.getObjectForApplicationId(PersistentIDROF.java:435)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.PersistentIDROF.getObject(PersistentIDROF.java:301)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.nextResultSetElement(ForwardQueryResult.java:130)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult$QueryResultIterator.next(ForwardQueryResult.java:282)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.detachCopyAll(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1176)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerProxy.detachCopyAll(JDOPersistenceManagerProxy.java:166)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.ra.impl.RAOrganizationStore.getRecords(RAOrganizationStore.java:136)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.ra.impl.RAOrganizationManagerImpl.getRecords(RAOrganizationManagerImpl.java:174)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.admin.actions.OrganizationAction.browse(OrganizationAction.java:246)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.admin.interceptors.UrlInterceptor.intercept(UrlInterceptor.java:47)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.admin.interceptors.MonitoringInterceptor.intercept(MonitoringInterceptor.java:47)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.admin.interceptors.TransactionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionInterceptor.java:36)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.admin.interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Who have an idea about resolving this issue.

Comment: Can you show your original class and modified class, and some details about how you are persisting and recovering objects ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define a member in the class concerned:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1113799434508676095L;
```

This solves the problem described in the message, by forcing the `serialVersionUID` of the local class to match what was put in the stream when you serialized the old version of the class, which would have been computed automatically over various class attributes if no `serialVersionUUD` field was present at that time.

It is possible that you altered the class in an incompatible way, which will then produce a different exception. See the Object Serialization Specification chapter on Versioning for details. However merely adding or removing a field doesn't have that effect.

Comment: you could actually explain *why* and *how* this would fix the issue, and given what constraints.

Comment: this is also don't resolve the problem.

Comment: @user2604148 Are you sure you copy/pasted it correctly? And do you really get exactly the same exception? With exactly the same message?

Comment: I add the stack Trace after implementation and trying to fix serialVersionUID, but I constate that stream classdesc serialVersionUID is generated each time and not fix

Comment: @ATEFCHAREF So why you accept this answer ??? i have the same problem , how did you solveit ?

Comment: @mohammed Err, because it's the correct answer? Clearly his comment is now obsolete.

Comment: you forget to add final keyword, use this:  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1113799434508676095L;

Comment: @ElmarAbbasov Actually there is nothing in the Object Serialization Specification that specifically requires `final`, but it's required by the code in `ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID()`, which is curious.

Comment: @ATEFCHAREF I would also like to know what you meant by 'constated', which is not a word in English, but if you're claiming that the `serialVersionUID' is always computed even when declared, you're mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)` in your object class. It kinda "overrides" the default behavior, even though it is declared as "private", so technically it should not. Basically, when java serializer needs to read an object from a stream, of class that has this method implemented, it will call that instead of doing its default thing.

So, you can implement a logic into it, that will read all the existing fields from the stream, and assign default values to those that are missing.

*Edit:* As @EJP points out (thanks, @EJP!), this does not quite work. You also need to define`private static long serialVersionUID` in your class, and set it to the "old" value you see in the exception.

Also, consider replacing Serializable with Externalizable for the future, it gives you some more flexibility, and transparency.  Extending `Externalizable` tells java that you intend to handle serialization yourself, and it will then not attempt to do its default thing that throws the exception.

In that case, implement `readExternal(ObjectInputStream in)` to read members from the stream one-by-one, and initialize those that are missing to some kind of default.

Comment: where to implement readObject(ObjectInputStream in), I did'nt understand your response, can you explain?

Comment: The class that you modified, that implements `Serializable`. You can add a `readObject` method to it, and implement the custom logic there.

Comment: I add this: 
     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
  throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
  identifier = (String) stream.readObject();
  country = (String) stream.readObject();
  dn = (String) stream.readObject();
  orgUnit = (String) stream.readObject();
  cn = (String) stream.readObject();
 }
but where I call this? it does'nt resolve the problem...

Comment: This won't fix the problem. The exception is thrown prior to invocation of this method if it exists. -1

Comment: @EJP indeed. I edited the answer to reflect your correction. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: @user2604148: you don't need to call it anywhere, java serialization will call the new method you added when it sees your class in the stream. I just edited my answer to explain why it does not resolve your problem: you need to also define `serialVersionUID` in your class. I forgot to mention that initially. Sorry about that.

Comment: sorry, this two does not fix the problem! I try to add the method and the old serial number... but same I have same exception always... and the method that I implemented was not invoked when debuging!!

Comment: If you get the same exception, that means that either the number you added is wrong or you added it to a wrong class, or declared it wrong. Look at the exception message closely,  it has "local class serialVersionUID". It should be the number that you added, and it should also match "streamdesc serialVersionUID".

Comment: @Dima He doesn't 'also' need to define a `serialVersionUID`. That should be *all* he needs to do. According to his deleted answer all he's done is add three string fields. That doesn't need a `readObject()`method.

Comment: @EJP, maybe, or maybe not. Depends on what are the fields he added, and how he wants them initialized. Deserialization does not invoke default constructors, so leaving new fields undefined may be a problem.

Comment: Initialization is a separate and possibly imaginary problem. The solution to *this* one is a `serialVersionUID` field, and *maybe*, for the possibly imaginary problem, 'also' a `readObject()` method. Not the other way round.

Comment: @Dima No. Why do you ask? Or are you just trolling?

Comment: @EJP it's been a while, but I don't remember asking you anything. Care to provide some context?

Comment: @Dima You asked whether I was a lawyer, but the moderators have been at it.