# Invalid class exception in apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to run a spark job using spark-submit. When I run it in eclipse the job runs without any issue. When I copy the same jar file to a remote machine and run the job there I get the below issue

```
17/08/09 10:19:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, ip-10-50-70-180.ec2.internal): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2231953621568687904, local class serialVersionUID = -6966587383730940799
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1829)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1986)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:253)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I saw some other links in SO and tried the below

1. Changed the version of spark jars to 2.11 from 2.10 which I was using before. Now the dependencies in pom look like this

   ```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.2</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>

   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.2</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-yarn_2.10 -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-yarn_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.2</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.2</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. I also checked that the version 2.11-2.0.2 exists in the jars folder of spark as suggested in a few links.
3. I also added  provided  in the dependencies as suggested in few links

None of the above helped. Any help would be of great help as I am stuck in this issue. Thanks in advance. Cheers

Edit 1: This is the spark-submit command

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class "com.abc.ingestion.GenericDeviceIngestionSpark" /home/hadoop/sathiya/spark_driven_ingestion-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar "s3n://input-bucket/input-file.csv" "SIT" "accessToken" "UNKNOWN" "bundleId" "[{"idType":"D_ID","idOrder":1,"isPrimary":true},{"idType":"HASH_DEVICE_ID","idOrder":2,"isPrimary":false}]"
```

Edit 2:

I also tried adding the variable **serialVersionUID = -2231953621568687904L;** to the related class but that didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Can you post your spark-submit command as well?

Comment: Sure. I will add it now

Comment: Version mismatch between the spark job which you submit. Please check the spark version in the cluster and add the same in pom file.

Comment: @JosePraveen I checked the spark version in the machine and it returned 
version 2.0.2. Hence I modified the version of spark to 2.0.2 in my pom file. Please see the dependencies which I have added

Comment: @SathiyaNarayanan I think the problem is w.r.t serialization. please check this [how resolve java.io.InvalidClassException: local class incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27655035/8035260)

Comment: Hi @JosePraveen Thanks for your prompt reply. I have already added the serialVersionUId variable to my class. That doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Why did you change to 2.11? Do you know what version of Scala is installed where you are running the code?

Comment: @cricket_007 No I checked the jar files in jars folder of spark and saw that most of them had the jar file names with suffix as follows **spark-yarn_2.11-2.0.2.jar** Hence I modified the pom to 2.11

Comment: Spark on your machine, or the remote?

Comment: @cricket_007 in remote machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue. I commented out all the dependencies and uncommented them one at a time. First I uncommented **spark_core** dependency and the issue got resolved. I uncommented another dependency in my project which again brought back the issue. Then on investigation I found that the second dependency was in turn having dependency of a different version(2.10) of spark_core which was causing the issue. I added exclusion to the dependency as below:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.data.utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>data-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

This resolved the issue. Just in case someone gets stuck on this issue. Thanks @JosePraveen for your valuable comment which gave me the hint.

Answer (score 2):

We see this issue when slightly different jar versions were being used on the Spark master and 1 or more of the Spark slaves.

I was facing this issue because I had only copied my jar to the master node. Once I copied the jar to all the slave nodes, my application started working just fine.